# Break Loop After No More Pages Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm paginating through orders inside Shopify. I'd like to break out of the loop once it hits the last page. The button that I use to click to paginate is still active and clickable on the last page the only thing different is that it has a property of "disabled". Typically, I would look for the "next" button and if isn't there, then loop will break. Not sure what to do in this case.

Here's my code that I know doesn't work.

```
while True:
    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@testid='Item-Content']/div[2]/div/div/span/span/a")]

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="AppFrameMain"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/nav/span[2]/button').click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        pass
```

Button HTML

```
<button type="button" class="p_2bbL9" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="TooltipContent304" disabled>
  <span class="p_2-hnq">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 20 20" class="p_v3ASA" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true">
    <path d="M17.707 9.293l-5-5a.999.999 0 1 0-1.414 1.414L14.586 9H3a1 1 0 1 0 0 2h11.586l-3.293 3.293a.999.999 0 1 0 1.414 1.414l5-5a.999.999 0 0 0 0-1.414" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic that you should use.

```
    while True:
    # your logic goes here
    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in
           driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@testid='Item-Content']/div[2]/div/div/span/span/a")]
    # exist loop if next button is disabled
    if not(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Next']").is_enabled()):
        break
    else:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Next']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks, that is close. The issue is the class name is dynamic on the button. Should it just be ("//button").click() ?

Comment: Updated the answer to use the `aria-label`, we may use `//button` but there is a possibility of having multiple buttons on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.Check the length count >0 then break else click.

```
 while True:
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button[aria-label="Next"][disabled]'))>0 :
       break
    else:
        driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button[aria-label="Next"]')[0].click()
```